# In Ruby, how can I reflect on classes contained within a module?

Tags: ruby, reflection, module

I'm using a library that lays its library out like this:

```
module Lib
  class A; end
  class B; end
  ...
end
```

I know that I can use `send` on an object to "call" a method known only at runtime (e.g., `foo.send(:bar, :baz_param=>42`). How can I do this at the class level?

In other words, I suspect there's a way to write something like this:

```
label = :Klass
MyModule.some_method(label).new
```

that executes, in effect, as:

```
MyModule::Klass.new
```

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as I posted the question, I had a brainwave:

`const_get`

Class names are treated as constants, and the method is defined for all modules, too, so the lookup scope can be restricted to that module only. Just remember to get the capitalization right:

```
MyModule.const_get(:Klass).new # => #<Klass:> #CORRECT

MyModule.const_get(:klass).new # => NameError: wrong constant name
```

Comment: `MyModule.const_get('klass'.capitalize.to_sym)` also works just fine if you're not confident in the capitalization of your input.